# Xcode Distribution Failed with Error: framework is not contained in a correctly named directory. It should be under "Frameworks"

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

As I want to upload my app I get the following error messages, when I upload the app.

I get the Crypto Swift Framework from the Swift Package Manager.

Can someone help me here please? I don't know what to do right now.

The error messages in text:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90680: "Invalid directory. The bundle Payload/Healthya.app/PlugIns/CryptoSwift.framework is not contained in a correctly named directory. It should be under "Frameworks"."

App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.krzyzanowskim.CryptoSwift' under the iOS application 'Healthya.app'."

App Store Connect Operation Warning
WARNING ITMS-90806: "CFBundleIdentifier collision. Each bundle must have a unique bundle identifier. The bundle identifier 'com.krzyzanowskim.CryptoSwift' is used in the bundles '[Payload/Healthya.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework, Payload/Healthya.app/PlugIns/CryptoSwift.framework]'"
```

Answer (score 1):

"More than one bundle" message suggests there's something fishy with the setup.
Either your SPM integration is faulty, and maybe duplicate with some manual integration, or it's an Xcode SPM integration issue.

The problem is that Xcode left CryptoSwift.o and added CryptoSwift.framework, while only one can exist at a time. The solution here is to delete `CryptoSwift.o` file.

[image]

in Xcode run "Product -> Clean Build Folder". This should remove leftovers and the next build should be just fine. I was able to reproduce the issue, but it's something that can be addressed by Xcode only.

[image]

Look at the produced .app bundle and check whether there's duplication there.

It should look similar to this:

[image]

[image]

Did you ask Apple about it already?

Edit: I did report that bug to SwiftPM and Xcode (FB8901104) and got a return message as fixed by 23 Feb 2023

Comment: Where I find the produced .app bundle?
I deleted the connection with SPM and get a new one.
I haven't asked Apple. But it looks like there is an issue at version 1.3.5.
With the version 1.3.3. it works.

Comment: But it looks like there is an issue at version 1.3.5. and 1.3.4.
With the version 1.3.3. it works.

Comment: You can find it in the Products group in the Xcode project.

Comment: @moxmlb can you maybe create new empty project and reproduce the issue there, or it's just when you update from previous version? You can try delete DerivedData and run  File -> Swift Packages -> Reset Package Cache, in Xcode. Maybe it's something with that

Comment: I deleted the DerivedData and Reseted the Package Cache in Xcode. I have now version 1.3.3. and the update works. I will check again with version 1.3.5. give me one second

Comment: the error get if I m updating from version 1.3.3. to 1.3.4. or 1.3.5. 
With the version 1.3.3. it works

Comment: don't do an update, it looks like Xcode can't update between these two versions and left old artefacts. Just remove SPM entry in Xcode, delete DerivedData, execute "Reset Package Cache",  and re-add v1.3.5. It should work now.

Comment: Did it like you described above, but same error. Only Version 1.3.3. works for me

Comment: Can't reproduce this scenario. The upgrade workaround works for me, and I can see leftovers that need to be removed manually. Can you reproduce it with a new project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have downloaded a Project from Source Control

Error 1: Make Sure your FrameWork directory is in the same path showing in XCode

Error 2: Remove PodFile.lock and also remove crypto framework and install correct version identify from Package.json run pod install

Step 3: Clean Xcode build

Step 4: Rebuild

Comment: I use only the Swift Package Manager, and not pod

Comment: I see no Framework directory in Finder